# Update existed docker image and all contains once Dockerfile changed

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I build a docker images and created multiple docker container based on the images. All containers run ok. If I have some command need to change in dockerfile.containers
I have to stop all containers and remove them. rebuild a new docker images and create containers again. Since I cannot just build a small part of image and build contain, then attach to origin one.
 If there a better way to do it?

Comment: treat your running containers as cattle not pets ... cut a fresh docker image ... push then bounce ... containers are static and should not be updated just replace with new ... leave them running during build process the bounce is very quick ... if you demand a seamless bounce you can launch the fresh container to co-mingle with prior versions then starve traffic to old ones just before you drop them ... that is a orchestration issue not a docker issue

Comment: That's right, you have to rebuild your images and restart containers for the changes in Dockerfile to take effect. It's the intended way to do it.

And yes, you can build part of the image, but not directly. As far as I remember - docker uses caching if it can for every step of the building process and reuses the cached state if the command did not change.

Comment: yes, I can build new image and attached to container but the thing is I need to remove existed container and reattached them. so it is kind of inconvenient if I have multiple containers link together and all containers build at the same images